# How to avoid variable name collisions in my init file?

Tags: init-file, dynamic-scoping

I noticed [spacemacs](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs) puts things like autosave and backup files in `~/.emacs.d/.cache/` and I'd like to use that idea in my own setup.

From [spacemacs/core/core-load-paths.el](https://github.com/syl20bnr/spacemacs/blob/master/core/core-load-paths.el#L32-L33)

```
(defconst spacemacs-cache-directory
  (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory ".cache/"))
```

I considered adding this to my own init.el,

```
(defconst cache-directory
  (expand-file-name (concat user-emacs-directory ".cache/"))
```

but without the "spacemacs" prefix, "cache-directory" seems like a dangerously generic name, likely to collide with something at some point.

I'm still new to emacs, and I don't know enough about scoping in elisp to say whether this is a serious concern. Should I name it something silly like "ivan-cache-directory", or is there a best practice people stick to? Or is this not actually worth worrying about?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a should-be-unique prefix is recommended.

For init file code I like to use `my-` because:

1. it is suitably unlikely to conflict with anything.
2. it's short, but meaningful.
3. it's not my name -- so when I share code with other people it reads just as well in their init file as it does in my own.